# remove time and timezone from DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, asp.net-core, datetime

my goal => 5/26/2022
but I can't remove time from date. => 5/26/2022 12:00:00 AM

How can I remove the time without using ToShortDateString()?

```
Value.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

Example;
https://dotnetfiddle.net/xWELRP

Comment: Do you want to strip the time part only for display, or is it irrelevant for your data?

Comment: I save the Date as "2022-05-31 00:00:00+03" in database. 
In the Get Update method, I send this date to the input.
The date appears as "2022-05-31 00:00:00+03" in the input.

Comment: Better do not store dates as strings in the database. Almost all database products have specific data types or dates (and times).

Answer (score 0):

You could try with

```
   DateTime.Now.Date
```

if your variable is type of DateTime,itwould have hour minute and second by default,it would set the time to 0:00:00

Comment: I want to remove the time. Just date.  Not 5/26/2022 0:00:00, my goal 5/26/2022

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **.Net6**, then you can use [`DateOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0) struct,

```
var dateOnly = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTimeOffset.Now.Date);
Console.WriteLine(dateOnly);
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6NIArd)

Comment: unfortunately im using net5

Comment: .Net5 does not have any data structure to store only dates, what exactly you are trying to achieve with only date?

Comment: You know that .NET 5 is out of support? See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: i want to save only date when saving to database. because when I get the date in the frontend, the date is returned as "5/26/2022 12:00:00 AM" in the input.

Comment: Your question did not mention that a database is involved. Better choose the correct data type in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{data:d}");
```

There are a few other format constraint keywords where you can find the one that works best for you, this is a very easy way to do it.

[image]